# jQuery's addClass works but browser doesn't apply new class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, on my page I have navigation bar that helps to move around it. After clicking I remove .active class from previous < li> and give it to new one. In console everything looks nice but on the page there is a problem. I can't see the .active class properties in active < li> and scrolling around it isn't working like it used to before clicking. Here is my page and code:
https://kreha6.github.io/MacopediaTask/
(it's hard to describe what's exactly happening :) )

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function scrollToId(id){
    id = id.replace("link", "");
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
   }

$("#navbar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
  scrollToId(this.id);
 });

});
```

SCSS:

```
.active{
  a{
    background-color: $transparent !important;
    text-decoration: overline;
    text-decoration-color: $color1;
   }
}
```

edit:
I changed my code to add class to parent element like this:

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Bootstrap adds active class to < li> which is a's parent, I tried to do the same thing. For some reason it doesn't work. Anyone know why?

Comment: That SCSS will translate into `.active a` selector targeting an **a** element inside the one with class `.active` but you are actually adding the class to the a element ... and then nothing will happen there is no element inside a.active to target

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are writing it wrong in SCSS because in JQ

```
$("#navbar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {
  $('.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active'); //here you add class active to the clicked 'a' element
```

So the `a` element has class `.active` on click. But, as I understood from the comments you want the `li` to have class `active` , so use:

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('active')
```

and also in CSS you should be more specific, because you could have some styles already set for `li.active a`, for e.g. write:

```
#navbar ul.nav li.active > a { /*styles*/ }
```

Comment: I need to add .active class to <a> parent element - < li> (just like bootstrap does). I tried : $(this).parent().addClass('active'); , but it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: add $(this).parents('li').addClass('active')

Comment: can you edit your original question with your HTML ? it might be a problem with the html structure. also take a look at the console, is there any error ?

Comment: no errors in the console, code is here: https://github.com/Kreha6/MacopediaTask/blob/scrolling/index.html

Comment: then it means that the jQ code is working. the problem is with the SCSS. you should try a more specific path in SCSS. for example : `#navbar ul.nav li.active > a { /*styles*/ } `

Comment: still no effect :(

Comment: Ok, I've made a little mistake applying your previous solution. I rewrote it and now everything works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the parent div, try to change `$("#navbar > ul > li > a")` with `$("#navbar > ul > li")`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function scrollToId(id){
        id = id.replace("link", "");
        $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
       'slow');
}

$("#navbar > ul > li").click(function(e) {
   $('.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   e.preventDefault();
   scrollToId(this.id);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I look at your website, your classes are not targeted, change the way they are done in CSS, look the image I have attached for you, the class .active not applied[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgeqo.png)

as you see the grey colour is overriden, but your classes get applied in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you can write script as `$(this).parent().addClass('active');`